# Django Backend doesn't return json to Angular frontend

Tags: python, django, angular

I have web project, backend on  Django , frontend on Angular

Backend started as:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 192.168.1.195:8080
```

Frontend started as:

```
ng serve --host 192.168.1.195
```

on the  4200 port.

On the Django in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST section in settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://192.168.1.195:8080',
    'http://localhost:8081',
    'http://192.168.1.195:4200',
    'http://127.0.0.1:4200',

)
```

On the frontend side:

***service.ts:***

```
var apiUrl = "http://192.168.1.195:8080";

var httpLink = {
//  getAllEmployee: apiUrl + "/api/employee/getAllEmployee",
  getAllEmployee: apiUrl + "/api/hosts_groups",
  deleteEmployeeById: apiUrl + "/api/employee/deleteEmployeeById",
  getEmployeeDetailById: apiUrl + "/api/employee/getEmployeeDetailById",
  saveEmployee: apiUrl + "/api/employee/saveEmployee"
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpProviderService {

  constructor(private webApiService: WebApiService) { }

  public getAllEmployee(): Observable<any> {
    return this.webApiService.get(httpLink.getAllEmployee);
  }
```

***home.component.ts***

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      closeResult = '';
      employeeList: any = [];
      constructor(private router: Router, private modalService: NgbModal,
        private toastr: ToastrService, private httpProvider : HttpProviderService) { }
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getAllEmployee();
      }
      async getAllEmployee() {
        this.httpProvider.getAllEmployee().subscribe((data : any) => {
          if (data != null && data.body != null) {
            var resultData = data.body;
            if (resultData) {
              this.employeeList = resultData;
            }
          }
        },
        (error : any)=> {
            if (error) {
              if (error.status == 404) {
                if(error.error && error.error.message){
                  this.employeeList = [];
                }
              }
            }
          });
      }
```

When i call `http://192.168.1.195:8080/api/hosts_groups` django returns json as excpected
and in console i see :

```
"GET /api/hosts_groups HTTP/1.1" 200 85
```

But in case when i call

```
http://192.168.1.195:4200
```

no json returned although in console i see:

```
"OPTIONS /api/hosts_groups HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Comment: Your frontend code is incomplete.

Comment: @Klaus D. , i edited my question

Comment: http://192.168.1.195:4200  is the URL for the server to serve your front-end.  (that would be index.html along with built angular scripts/css)  But this is the server that "ng-serve" generates... a local node server for debugging.  Your back end/API (your Django server) is serving on another port.   You shouldn't expect :4200 to return any JSON.  (The options responses are from Django :8080... presumably your initial page calls an API endpoint to retrieve some data.)